# Add Text to Merged Cells In Excel Spreadsheet Using EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, text, epplus

does anyone know how do I check if there is any file in a directory, then if there isn't, how can I add text "content not found" onto the excel spreadsheet in merged cells?

This is what I have tried:

```
   foreach (string subdir in filesindirectory)
            {
                string[] splitter = subdir.Split('\\');
                string folderName = splitter[splitter.Length - 1];
                ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(folderName); //create new worksheet
                ImageCount = 0;
                foreach (string img in Directory.GetFiles(subdir))
                {
                    if (subdir.Length == 0)
                    {

                        ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Merge = true;
                        ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
                        ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                        ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                        ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f0f3f5"));
                    }
```

**Question: How to add text to merged cell in excel spreadsheet using EPplus?**
Please help me on this, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use

```
ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Value = "content not found";
```

or

```
ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "content not found";
```

Comment: hi @Chawin, have tried the following method but nothing appeared on my excel spreadsheet. Please look at my updated post thanks!

Comment: @FeliciaSoh I've added my code directly after `ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f0f3f5"));` and it works perfectly, is the code within your if function ever running?